# Cropping an image to a "perfect" square like native Photos app

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiimage

Whilst working on a functionality for viewing embedded images that get fetched from one of our servers, one of the requirements is to make an overview page, where all images are displayed, in a fasion like the iOS Native Photos App (square tiles, in rows of 4/5 and when tapped, displays the image screen-wide.

This has been successfully implemented, except that the images were morphed (image aspects were never taken into account). Thus, they have asked me to devise a method to crop the image, so the original aspect stays unchanged.

In order to do this, I was thinking of first resizing the image until the width reaches the max width I want it to be ((screenwidth - 10) / 4 - 5).

- If the height of the image is smaller than the width, I set the height to be equal to the width, and crop the width accordingly (with aspect unchanged).
- If the height of the image is greater than the width, I just want to crop the height.

This is the method I am currently using:

```
//Images is an array/List with base64 strings
foreach (var image in Images)
{
    UIImage imageToAdd = UIImage.LoadFromData(NSData.FromArray(Convert.FromBase64String(image.Content)));

    var width = imageToAdd.Size.Width;
    var height = imageToAdd.Size.Height;

    //GlobalSupport.ScreenWidth is a static variable that contains the actual screensize
    var newWidth = (GlobalSupport.ScreenWidth - 10) / 4 - 5;

    var newHeight = height * newWidth / width;

    var widthToCrop = 0.0f;
    var heightToCrop = 0.0f;

    //If the new height is smaller than the new width, make the new height equal to the new width, and modify the new width accordingly.
    if (newHeight < newWidth)
    {
        newHeight = newWidth;
        newWidth = width * newHeight / height;

        widthToCrop = newWidth - newHeight;
    }
    //Or, if the new height is greater than the new width, just crop the height.
    else if (newHeight > newWidth)
    {
        heightToCrop = newHeight - newWidth;
    }

    UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(new SizeF(newWidth, newHeight));
    var cropRectangle = new RectangleF(-widthToCrop, -heightToCrop, newWidth, newHeight);
    imageToAdd.Draw(cropRectangle);
    imageToAdd = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

    UIButton btnToAdd = new UIButton(new RectangleF(-widthToCrop, -heightToCrop, newWidth, newHeight));

    btnToAdd.SetBackgroundImage(imageToAdd, UIControlState.Normal);

    btnToAdd.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //Displays a loading spinner
                GlobalSupport.EnableLoadingOverlay(true, NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString("txtOneMoment", "", ""));
            }).ContinueWith(task => InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    //Navigate to the full-screen image viewer
                    this.NavigationController.PushViewController(
                        new VCDCMPhotoDetails(
                            UIImage.LoadFromData(
                                NSData.FromArray(
                                    Convert.FromBase64String(image.Content)))), true);

                    GlobalSupport.EnableLoadingOverlay(false, "");
                }));
    };

    //Add btn to the scrollable view's children
    scrollView.AddSubview(btnToAdd);
}
```

This method works great, except for one thing: if the `new height` is smaller than the `new width`, the `new height` and `new width` successfully get modified, but after the `ImageToAdd.Draw(RectangleF)` the `Size` of the `ImageToAdd` still has the `new width` value, instead of the cropped width (that is, if I can assume that, if I draw an image with -20 as its x-value, the width gets modified with -20 as well).

I don't know if this is the right way to do it. If it isn't, then all help is welcome! If this is the right way to do it, but I'm missing something, please let me know! Thanks in advance!

When cropping the image, the x-coordinate is equal to the width of the image, minus the max width of a thumbnail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNm7k.png

After cropping, the image still had the original new width, instead of the cropped width: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rabeY.png

The resulting grid of images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/opo2f.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me just show you a proper procedure on how to crop the image with a FILL operation. The code is in Swift but you should have no trouble porting it:

```
    public static func resampleImageToSize(image: UIImage!, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let originalWidth = image.size.width
        let originalHeight = image.size.height
        let originalRatio = originalWidth/originalHeight

        let targetRatio = size.width/size.height

        var targetFrame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

        if originalRatio>targetRatio {
            // crop width
            let targetHeight = size.height
            let targetWidth = targetHeight * originalRatio
            targetFrame = CGRect(x: (size.width-targetWidth)*0.5, y: (size.height-targetHeight)*0.5, width: targetWidth, height: targetHeight)

        } else if originalRatio<targetRatio {
            // crop height
            let targetWidth = size.width
            let targetHeight = targetWidth / originalRatio
            targetFrame = CGRect(x: (size.width-targetWidth)*0.5, y: (size.height-targetHeight)*0.5, width: targetWidth, height: targetHeight)
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        image.drawInRect(targetFrame)
        let outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return outputImage
    }
```

So this is a general method that takes in an original image and returns an image with a size of your choice. In your case that is the size of the icons you want to display. The operation here is *fill*, if you need to *fit* the image all you need to do is swap `<` and `>` in both `if` statements.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is easiest to achieve with creating an image view with the size of your target image size. Then set your image to it and set the content mode to scale aspect fill and simply create a screenshot of the view (you can find very easy solutions for that on the web).

From your question I can not see if you have an issue at all or what it is. But one thing is bothering me. The line

```
RectangleF(-widthToCrop, -heightToCrop, newWidth, newHeight)
```

Will crop it the way you will always get the bottom right part of the image. You should most likely center it:

```
RectangleF(-widthToCrop*0.5, -heightToCrop*0.5, newWidth, newHeight)
```

Ok I think I found your problem. The frame you compute is the frame on which you should draw the image to put it on the square. But when you begin image context you should set the size to be a square. So if the width is larger the size should be `(newHeight, newHeight)` otherwise `(newWidth, newWidth)`. The button frame makes no sense to me either. Why are you using the rectangle that should be used only to redraw the image?

Comment: The issue is that when I put the image in another control, like a UIButton, the image has a transparent space on its right side (this is the "cropped" space).

For example: if I have an image of 300x200, and want it 50x50, I resize it to fill the max height, and modify the width accordingly. Using the method described in the OP, I end up with an image that's not of Size 50x30, but more like 75x30 (in its properties, when looking at the image, it's perfectly square though, just the transparent space is there). this way, the image gets morphed in the control anyway, even though I cropped it.

Comment: I modified the button frame as an experiment to see if it had any effect. I changed it back already. I will try to modify the image context frame as you suggested, and I'll let you know the results! Thanks!

Comment: I changed my implementation, so I begin the image context with a square (87x87), I made a rectangle(0, 0, 87, 87) and call the .Draw() on my image, retrieve the ImageFromCurrentContext, but it's still morphed. I used panoramas to check the results, and they are either stretched out (height > width) or really fat (height < width). Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing a point in what you are doing. The context size must be of target size but the frame must be out of bounds and must preserve the original ratio so it is not stretch. Let me give you a swift example, it should be easy to port. The method will accept the original image and a target size and perform a FILL procedure on the image and return a cropped image.